# On some optimal containers of a set of points on the 2D plane

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, covering

Given a set of N points in general position on the plane, the problem is to give efficient algorithms to find

1. the smallest semicircular region (semidisk) that contains the points
2. the smallest circular segment that contains the points (2 variants - 'smallest' could mean either of 'least area' or 'least perimeter').
3. the smallest sector that contains the points (again, 2 variants)

I am not aware of previous works on these questions.

**Note:** An O(N^2) algorithm for question 1 has been proposed in https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.10245. No proof of optimality was given, so there could be faster algorithms.

Some thoughts on question 2 are also given there but no algorithm.

Higher dimensional analogs of these questions - hemisphere, spherical segment etc..- arise naturally.

**Note:** The question of finding **the largest semidisk/sector/circular segment contained in a given convex region C** too seems unexplored. It is not hard to see that for a given C, the largest semidisk it contains should necessarily have both end points of the diameter on the boundary of C. Based on this property, a basic algorithm (complexity estimate: O(N^4)) has been proposed at https://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2020/07/largest-semidisk-inside-convex-polygon.html

Comment: Just to add slightly to your arXiv Lemma 2 concerning how the points hull $P$ touches the minimum semicircle diameter: If $P$ only touches the semicircle arc at exactly one point $x$, then $x$ must be the midpoint (i.e., highest) point of the arc. Otherwise $P$ touches the arc in at least two points.

Comment: Yes; that is a property of the hull and the semidisk that had better be stated explicitly - although the subsequent arguments assume it implicitly. Even the 'observation' regarding the 'vertex at the largest minimum distance from an edge' needs tightening - in general, for an edge E on the hull, there appear to be 2 vertices (not 1) which are both at the largest minimum distance from E. But the rotating calipers type of argument still seems to hold. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4010764/smallest-enclosing-circle-for-a-convex-polygon/4111588#4111588) reference we have an algorithm to determine the smallest circle containing a convex polygon. Follows a python code which uses this algorithm to find the smallest semi-circle container. The focused example is the same referenced in the OP in the cited paper. I hope the script is self explained. I am a early python programmer...

```
import math
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

data0 = [[2.30, 0.15],[0.63, 0.41],[0.37, 0.59],[0.79, 1.47],[2.32, 1.87],[3.6107, 0.72],[2.73, 0.14]]

def sub(p1,p2):
    return list(map(lambda i, j: i-j,p1,p2))
def add(p1,p2):
    return list(map(lambda i, j: i+j,p1,p2))
def cline(p,v,u):
    v = [element * u for element in v]
    return list(map(lambda i, j: i+j,p,v))
def max_secant(data):
    n = len(data)
    dmax = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            d = LA.norm(sub(data[i],data[j]))
            if d > dmax:
                dmax = d
                i0 = i
                j0 = j                   
    return (i0, j0)

def verify(data, feasible):
    internal = True
    error = 0.005
    for i in range(len(data)):
        dif = LA.norm(sub(data[i],feasible[0]))-feasible[1]
        if dif > error:
            internal = False
    return internal

def polar_form(triangle):
    (x1,y1) = triangle[0]
    (x2,y2) = triangle[1]
    (x3,y3) = triangle[2]
    M = np.array([[2*(x2-x1),2*(y2-y1)],[2*(x2-x3),2*(y2-y3)]]) 
    b = np.array([-(x1**2-x2**2+y1**2-y2**2),-(x3**2-x2**2+y3**2-y2**2)])
    (x0, y0) = list(np.linalg.solve(M,b))
    r = LA.norm([x1-x0,y1-y0])
    return [[x0,y0], r]

def collect_triangles(data, i0, j0):
    triangs = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if i not in [i0, j0]:
            triangs.append([data[i0],data[i],data[j0]])
    return triangs


def rotate(data):
    data0 = []
    n = len(data)
    dummy = data[0]
    for i in range(n-1):
        data0.append(data[i+1])
    data0.append(dummy)
    return data0

def take_extremals(data):
    breaks = []
    sant = 1
    v = sub(data[1],data[0])
    n = len(data)
    for i in range(1,n-2):
        s = np.sign(np.dot(v,sub(data[i+1],data[i])))
        if (sant != s):
            breaks.append(i)
        sant = s
    if len(breaks) == 1:
        breaks.append(n-1)
    return breaks

def mirror(data, p, v):
    reflected = []
    vn = LA.norm(v)
    n = len(data)
    v = [v[0]/vn,v[1]/vn]
    for i in range(n):
        v0 = np.dot(sub(data[i],p),v)
        v1 = [v[0]*v0,v[1]*v0]
        v2 = add(p, v1)
        v2 = [2*v2[0],2*v2[1]]
        pr = sub(v2, data[i])
        reflected.append(pr)
    return reflected

def glue(data1, data2):
    sdata = []
    n1 = len(data1)
    for i in range(n1):
        sdata.append(data1[i])
        n2 = len(data2)
    for i in range(n2):
        sdata.append(data2[n2-i-1])
    return sdata

def select(data, k1, k2):
    datas = []
    for i in range(k1, k2+1):
        datas.append(data[i])
    return datas

def best_circle(data1):
    (k1, k2) = take_extremals(data1)
    p0b = data1[0]
    vb = sub(data1[1],data1[0])
    datas = select(data1, k1, k2)
    datam = mirror(datas,p0b,vb)
    dataf = glue(datam, datas)

    (i0, j0) = max_secant(dataf)
    v = sub(dataf[i0],dataf[j0])
    r = 0.5*LA.norm(v)
    p1 = add(dataf[i0],dataf[j0])
    p0 = [element*0.5 for element in p1]
    triangles = collect_triangles(dataf,i0,j0)
    polar = []
    polar.append([p0,r])

    for i in range(len(triangles)):
        polar.append(polar_form(triangles[i]))

    feasible = []
    for i in range(len(polar)):
        if verify(dataf,polar[i]):
            feasible.append(polar[i])
    
    bestr = math.inf
    for i in range(len(feasible)):
        [pc, r] = feasible[i]
        if r < bestr:
            bestr = r
            bestcirc = feasible[i]
    return(bestcirc, p0b, vb)

########################
####  main program  ####
########################

data1 = data0
circmin = math.inf
for i in range(len(data0)):
    (circ, p0x, vx) = best_circle(data1)
    if circ[1] < circmin:
        circmin = circ[1]
        bestcirc = circ
        p0b = p0x
        vb = vx
    data1 = rotate(data1)
print(bestcirc)

#############################
#### plotting the result ####
#############################

(figure, axes) = plt.subplots()
(cx,cy) = bestcirc[0]
r = bestcirc[1]
poly = Polygon(data0)
(x, y) = poly.exterior.xy

xmin = cx - 1.1*r
xmax = cx + 1.1*r
ymin = cy - 1.1*r
ymax = cy + 1.1*r
axes.set_xlim((xmin,xmax))
axes.set_ylim((ymin,ymax))
uncolored_circle = plt.Circle( (cx,cy), r, fill = False)

axes.set_aspect( 1 )
axes.add_artist( uncolored_circle )
plt.plot(x,y)
v12 = vb
nv12 = LA.norm(v12)
v12 = [v12[0]/nv12,v12[1]/nv12]
s1x = cx - v12[0]*r
s1y = cy - v12[1]*r
s2x = cx + v12[0]*r
s2y = cy + v12[1]*r
plt.plot([s1x,s2x],[s1y,s2y])
plt.title( 'Result' )
plt.show()
```

[image]