# Biconvex Lens - an 'oriented' convex container for planar point sets

Tags: computational-geometry

We continue [On some optimal containers of a set of points on the 2D plane](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361590/on-some-optimal-containers-of-a-set-of-points-on-the-2d-plane).

Let us define a **biconvex lens** as the intersection of two circular disks - not necessarily of the same radii. Such a figure has an 'oriented' nature - the special orientation being the line joining the two centers.

**Question:** Given a set of n points on the plane to find the smallest biconvex lens that contains them all. A brute-force O(n^7) algorithm can be found very easily. But what is the optimal algorithm? Is there (say) a randomized incremental algorithm on the lines given in [https://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/754/Lects/754lects.pdf](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Emount/754/Lects/754lects.pdf) (page 45)?

**Note 1:** In the above definition, 'Smallest' could mean smallest area or smallest perimeter - I don't have an example where the two optimizations yield different biconvex lenses.

**Note 2:** How constraining the two radii of the lens to be equal could impact the algorithm(s) I am not sure.

**Note 3:** As noted above, the biconvex lens is an 'oriented convex container' - a bunch of questions on this type of figures (some questions have been solved subsequently) were recorded at pages linked to https://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2023/04/oriented-containers-again-biconvex.html.

Comment: For a *lens* (equal radii), I count $6$ degrees-of-freedom (DOF) in the plane: $2 \times 2$ for the diameter endpoints, the common radius, and the "sector displacement": distance from the diameter $\pm$ to the circles. So not easy to pin all these DOFs down.

Comment: Thank you. But can one not think of some 'perturbative' approach - say find the smallest containing circle or ellipse first and then work from there towards the smallest lens? The smallest circle can be done in linear time; not sure about the smallest ellipse but it must be much less than n^6.

Comment: It is known that a minimum area ellipse must touch at least three points. An analogous result for a minimum area lens would be a step forward.

Comment: Thanks again. Found that a randomized incremental algorithm does indeed work for the least area containing ellipse - https://github.com/dorshaviv/lowner-john-ellipse. One would guess that the same algorithm with limited changes would find the least perimeter containing ellipse as well - a further guess here is that there being no closed form for the ellipse perimeter need not prevent us from finding a least perimeter ellipse.