# Smallest Semi-ellipses that contain a convex n-gon

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, conic-sections

**Definition:** Let us define a *semi-ellipse* as either of the two halves into which an elliptical region is cut by any line that passes through its center. Obviously, all semi-ellipses that come from any given ellipse have same area and any given semi-ellipse determines a unique full ellipse.

**Question:** Given a convex n-gon, how could one find the least area semi-ellipse that can contain it? We need to find the full-ellipse and bisecting line that give the semi-ellipse.

Note 1: In the question, we can replace area with perimeter and so on.

Note 2: In the comments at [Biconvex Lens - an 'oriented' convex container for planar point sets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444570/biconvex-lens-an-oriented-convex-container-for-planar-point-sets), we mentioned the algorithmic problems of finding the least area and least perimeter full ellipses that contain a specified convex n-gon.